# spring-boot log runtime exceptions from new thread

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, logging, exception

I have a rest API on my spring-boot 1.3.5.RELEASE application, from which a process is started asynchronously using a ThreadPoolExecutor.

My problem is that the async process happens to throw runtime exceptions for scenarios that were not handled but the stacktrace does not go in my logs. I am using log4j.

This is a big issue, because it takes a lot of time to debug and see what the actual problem is.

I am aware of the @ControllerAdvice, but I think it's context ends when the new thread is started and spring no longer intercepts the Exceptions.

How can I configure the ThreadPoolExecutor to redirect the uncought exceptions to the spring context or how should I approach this issue?

I am looking for a general solution to catch these types of exceptions and add their stacktrace to the appender, as I don't know where a developer will start a new thread which will crash with an uncaught exception

Let's say that the rest looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/api/test")
public void doSomething() {
    ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(10, 10, 10 , TimeUnit.SECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(10, true));
    threadPoolExecutor.execute(() -> {
        throw new RuntimeException("some exception");
    });
}
```

Comment: Instead of handling threadpool by your own try using `@Async` annotation.
Methods annotated with `@Async` will run on a separate thread. Then if a exception occured you can handle it with `@ExceptionHandler` in your controller

Comment: It is a legacy application and will take a lot of refactoring

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a @ControllerAdvice, injecting Throwable into it and call logging?